# FIWARE IoT Agent: can the IoT agent send data to multiple context broker

Tags: fiware

I am using the [MQTT IoT agent](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-IoTAgent-Cplusplus) to send data to my [fiware context broker](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/), I am wondering if I can send data from my IoT agent to multiple context brokers. Is that possible? if yes how to?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MQTT IoT-Agent is connected to a specific Context Broker instance depending on the Service provision. If the Service Context Broker instance is not configured, then the "ngsi_urls" parameter is used.

Therefore, yes, you can deliver information to multiple ContextBroker instances but only one per defined FIWARE service.

If you want to send the information of one single service to multiple instances of Context Brokers I think you may send it to one and then federate the other instances. To learn about Context Broker instances federations you should check the ContextBroker related documents.

Thanks for using IDAS and sorry for a so delayed response (we have been slower regading support due to an internal migration process).